# How to check if Azure credentials are valid in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, I have Azure Helper which I am getting vm size list.

My question how to check is credentials is good or not and throw error if it is not good.

My Azure Helper looks like:

```
  public async Task<bool> AzureChecker(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenantId, string subscriptionId, string location)
    {
        try
        {
            var credentials = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId,
                AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud); 
            Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials);
            ComputeManagementClient client = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
            var vmSizes = await client.VirtualMachineSizes.ListAsync(location);
            if (vmSizes != null)
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: if the credentials are wrong the Authenticate method would fail right ?

Comment: @Aravind I updated my question, actually when i try also with bad credntials every time it is returning true somehow, I dont want to check vm-s but I need only check authneticate is failing or not, I assigned some value to authenticate method but it is never null of course and there is no option check is credential is true or not

Comment: @Liam always returning true with badcredentials I tested tyoe everywhere test for subId and etc. but again it returns true

Comment: in the above code why have you not used the client secret, tenantID ?

Comment: @Aravind I am using all fields which are required

Comment: @Aravind actually I dont want to chcek vms if it is any, i grabbed this one from my helper method. So situation is I have also checker controller means when I create some credentials before posting data I need to check is credentials are good or not, I did it for aws and for openstack alrady and they are working fine but in azure I can not find any approach

Comment: the code on azure docs uses all of it to validate your service principal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication but am not really sure why incorrect credentials don't give you  an unauthorized exception.

Comment: @Aravind I also checked this article but did not find validate authentication, so in short I need use all or some of properties from helper method for checking cause I am exactly saving this fields, I dont need url or some another properties

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov, you may take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/a26a21a066467055b9b121f4c2201dca857959cb/src/ResourceManagement/Azure.Fluent/Azure.cs#L921).

Comment: @IvanYang unfortunately I did not find any suitable method for me.

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov, I went through the source code, and tried all the authenticate method, actually it did nothing about authenticate. Can you please raise the issue in the Feedback section of this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication)?